# Adding existing s3 bucket images to strapi project

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, strapi

- Strapi Version: 4.15.4
- Operating System: windows 10
- Database: better-sqlite3
- Node Version: v18.18.1
- NPM Version: 10.2.4

I have some images in the s3 bucket. I want to add those images to the strapi project. I have a user table containing the name, age, and image. and when I create a new user I want to link an image from the s3 bucket to the strapi project. Without re-uploading again to strapi. I am using graplQl and nextJs. how can I do that? I saw one plugin that is `strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3`. But how can I link existing s3 images when creating a new user?